# How to remove the "b" character and quotation marks in python

Tags: python, openldap

How to remove the "b" character and quotation marks in python. Here's the code:

```
if 'number' in element[0][1]:
    write.wrirerow([[*element[0][1]['mail'], [*element[0][1]['number']]])
else:
    write.writerow(*[element[0][1]['mail'])
```

I tried using the character filter